Unable to have layergroup created be serialized to XML file
I'm using the GeoServer 2.26.0 REST API to create Workspaces, DataStore, Layers, Styles and LayerGroups. Everything seems to work fine except for the creation of the LayerGroups.
They are created, but they are not persisted to XML file. When GeoServer is restarted they dissapear.
In the log Exception callstack, those two errors are generated for each creation a new LayerGroup:
...
15 Nov. 17:29:04 DEBUG  [geoserver.config] - Persisted jdk.proxy3.$Proxy60 to global.xml
15 Nov. 17:29:04 ERROR  [geoserver.rest] - Error persisting LayerGroupInfoImpl[Decoupage_administratif] to workspaces/gonet140_kamouraska/layergroups/Decoupage_administratif.xml
org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogException: Error persisting LayerGroupInfoImpl[Decoupage_administratif] to workspaces/gonet140_kamouraska/layergroups/Decoupage_administratif.xml
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerConfigPersister.persist(GeoServerConfigPersister.java:632)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerConfigPersister.addLayerGroup(GeoServerConfigPersister.java:600)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerConfigPersister.handleAddEvent(GeoServerConfigPersister.java:89)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogEventDispatcher.dispatch(CatalogEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl.event(CatalogImpl.java:1902)
...

...
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Unexpected item null whose type is not among: [interface org.geoserver.catalog.LayerInfo, interface org.geoserver.catalog.LayerGroupInfo]
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Unexpected item null whose type is not among: [interface org.geoserver.catalog.LayerInfo, interface org.geoserver.catalog.LayerGroupInfo]
-------------------------------
    at org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister$ReferenceCollectionConverter.writeCompleteItem(XStreamPersister.java:1357)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.marshal(CollectionConverter.java:75)
...

I'm pretty sure this is not a permission issue. The host is a Debian 11 server and in the GeoServer data_dir all directories have execution and write permissions for any users.
I have several LayerGroup that I create, with varying amoung of sub Layers and LayerGroups. All of them fail with the same error. In the call stack there is a clue that maybe some property is null but with no mention of which property it is.
I enabled VERBOSE logging but don't see anything else that could clue me in has to what the problem is.
For reference the data sent in the /rest/layergroups POST is formatted in JSON.
Here is an example:
{
  "layerGroup": {
    "name": "Decoupage_administratif",
    "mode": "container",
    "title": "Découpage administratif",
    "abstractTxt": "",
    "workspace": {
      "name": "test"
    },
    "publishables": {
      "published": [
        {
          "name": "limite_kamouraska_mrc_s"
        },
        {
          "name": "limite_kamouraska_mun_s"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

and the headers are:
url = f"{geoserver_url}/rest/layergroups"
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

One thing I could add is that the layergroups are created last, after all other feature layers and styles. To make sure they all exists before creating the layergroup.
Is there anything else I could enable or try to troubleshoot this issue ?

It looks like something is not being set, try requesting one of the existing groups and comparing the json to see what's different

@IanTurton I can't retreive any layergroup, even though I can see them in the GeoServer web interface. The error returned is: "No such layer group".

That is probably the problem - does http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layergroups/tasmania.json work?

I ended up using XML instead:
<layerGroup>
    <name>Decoupage_administratif</name>
    <mode>container</mode>
    <title>Découpage administratif</title>
    <abstractTxt></abstractTxt>
    <workspace>
        <name>gonet140_kamouraska</name>
    </workspace>
    <publishables>
        <published type="layer">
            <name>limite_kamouraska_mrc_s</name>            
        </published>
        <published type="layer">
            <name>limite_kamouraska_mun_s</name>            
        </published>        
    </publishables>
</layerGroup>


Adding the @type property with value 'layer' or 'layerGroup' seems to resolve this.
{
  "layerGroup": {
    "name": "Decoupage_administratif2",
    "mode": "container",
    "title": "Découpage administratif2",
    "abstractTxt": "",
    "workspace": {
      "name": "gonet140_kamouraska"
    },
    "publishables": {
      "published": [
        {
          "@type": "layer",
          "name": "limite_kamouraska_mrc_s"
        },
        {
            "@type": "layer",
          "name": "limite_kamouraska_mun_s"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

